# Integrate Laravel Socialite with React Native Frontend using Passport

Tags: laravel, react-native, laravel-passport, laravel-socialite

I have a Laravel server with socialite and passport. I installed the coderello plugin to have the grant_social type. When I authorize the social, I reply from laravel to the client with a JSON with the social auth token. How can I capture it from my react app so I can use to make API calls? And how should I login with social? Should I use manual redirect with a WebView or should I use the official social's SDKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved using a view as response that contains a script that calls `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` and in my React app I use onMessage callback inside the WebView.

Comment: can you show how/explain you did this, I'm trying to do the same